# Collection of open intervals contain collection of unbounded intervals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Can we express $(-\infty,b)$ and $(a,\infty)$ as follows ?

$$ (-\infty,b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n,b) $$

$$ (a, \infty) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (a,n) $$

and therefore, we can safely say that the collection of all open intervals contain the unbounded intervals. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes to the two expressions. No to the last statement. $[0,\infty)$ is an unbounded interval that is not open.

Comment: but $[0 , \infty) = \bigcup (\frac{1}{n}, \infty) $

Comment: You are mistaken.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "the collection of all open intervals contain the unbounded intervals".

Comment: $\cup_n (\frac{1}{n}, \infty) = (0,\infty)$.

Comment: $\bigcap_n (\frac{1}{n}, \infty) = [0, \infty)$

Comment: @Peruano: That is false. $\bigcap_n (\frac{1}{n}, \infty) = (1, \infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions of the unbounded intervals are correct.

They show to us that certain unbounded intervals are open, namely those of the form $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,a)$ (and trivially, $\Bbb R = (-\infty,\infty)$).

However, there are more unbounded intervals, namely $[a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, a]$.

Now all points of these, except $a$, are inside $(a,\infty)$, resp. $(-\infty, a)$. Therefore, they cannot pose problems for $[a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,a]$ being open. It remains to check if the openness condition is satisfied at $a$.

That is to say, we should find an $\epsilon > 0$ such that:

$$|b-a| < \epsilon \text{ implies } b \in [a,\infty)$$

and similarly for $(-\infty,a]$. Alternatively, disproving existence of such $\epsilon$ will establish that the intervals are not open.

Can you do this?